# Limit is less than the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose I have a convergent sequence $\{a_n\}$ with the property that 
$$ \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |a_n| < P $$
for some $P > 0$. My question is: does
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| \leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |a_n| $$
hold and, if yes, can I immediately write
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| < P $$
without proving anything? My answers would be 'yes' and 'yes', but maybe the inequality needs some justification.

(Note: Almost all 'similar questions' are about the limes superior. I'm not about asking anything about $\limsup$!)

Comment: It depends on what level you're at. If you think the proof is trivial, then you probably don't need to prove it. If you have to think about the proof of these facts, then you should probably prove them.

Answer (score 6):

Since the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is assumed to be convergent, also $\{|a_n|\}$ is convergent, so we can assume $a_n\ge0$.

Let's show that, if $P$ is an upper bound for $\{a_n\}$, then $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\le P$.

If $l>P$, then there exists $n$ with $|a_n-l|<l-P$, which is the same as
$$
P-l<a_n-l<l-P
$$
and this implies $a_n>P$, a contradiction.

Now the supremum is *by definition* an upper bound for the sequence, so
$$
l\le\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n<P
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_n)$ is convergent then so is $(|a_n|)$. Since
$$ |a_k| \leq \sup_n |a_n|< P$$ holds for every $k$  we have
$$ \lim_k |a_k| \leq \sup_n |a_n| < P$$
Depending on the context in which you are supposed to present this you may or may not pass directly to the conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

Your first statement is false, if $(|a_n|)$ is convergent then $(a_n)$ is absolutely convergent, not the other way around.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).